# Tridion templates in content manager is not accessible

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

When tried to access templates in Tridion content manager it shows error

`“Unable to get template types with id:#number”.`

Also the templates in content manager is not accessible

Comment: Hi Can you provide some more detail?  Are you trying to open a template within the CME?   Is your user an admin or have rights to open the templates?

Comment: Also, can you add the details of the error message in case they exist? And a bit more of an explanation what is the difference between: "tried to access templates in Tridion content manager" and "the templates in content manager is not accessible"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a Template Type defined in your Tridion.ContentManager.config file which cannot be loaded. Perhaps you uninstalled something and the configuration file hasn't been updated -- or you restored an old configuration which refers to a Template Type that isn't installed anymore.

Either way, looking up the exact ID in the configuration will tell you which type it is -- you  can probably figure it out from there. If it's something that isn't in a default Tridion installation and you don't need them, feel free to remove the line or comment it out. That should get rid of the error.